# How can we do the tooltip for HTML elements on mobile application using phone gap?

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Can any one suggest me good way to use tooltip for mobile application on iOS. I am using phone gap for my application. So Is it possible with jQuery? Can anyone suggest me some good blog for the tap and hold event tooltip?

Comment: Just a question out of curiosity, how you are planning to show the tooltip? I mean in desktop browsers hover triggers the tooltip, in mobile there is no hover. So how you want to trigger the tooltip?

Comment: `Can anyone suggest me some good blow for the same?`  Say what?

Comment: Is it possible for tap and hold event. When you tap and hold a button, I need to show the functionality of respective button in a tooltip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use a simple jQuery Mobile popup for this functionality:

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/pCuh4/

#### HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-alt-icon ui-icon-info ui-btn-a ui-btn-inline ui-popup-tooltip" data-transition="pop" data-overlay-theme="b" data-position-to="origin" id="hold-me" data-massage="This is a dynamic tooltip massage">Hold me for tooltip</a>
<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-alt-icon ui-icon-info ui-btn-a ui-btn-inline ui-popup-tooltip" data-transition="pop" data-overlay-theme="b" data-position-to="origin" id="hold-me2" data-massage="This is a second dynamic tooltip massage">Hold me for second tooltip</a>                
<div data-role="popup" id="popupInfo" data-theme="b" style="max-width:350px;">
    <p>This is tooltip</p>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('taphold', '.ui-popup-tooltip', function(){ 
    $('#popupInfo').find('p').html($(this).attr('data-massage'));
    $('#popupInfo').popup("open",{positionTo: '#'+$(this).attr('id')});
});
```

As you can see I even made it dynamic.

Comment: I don't know the reason, but If I include jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js my on click events are not working. What is the reason for this?